# How does ActiveMQ Artemis determine when an MQTT subscriber is unsubscribed when the listening process terminates without unsubsribing

Tags: mqtt, activemq-artemis, telegraf-inputs-plugin

My understanding from a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74895113/activemq-artemis-telegraf-influxdb-is-there-a-way-to-clone-an-mqtt-message) is that setting the "clean" parameter to false in MQTT has the same effect as subscribing to a topic in JMS. That is, the message will be kept until all subscribers have received the message.

My question is, what if a subscriber/listener is on a PC that has crashed? When the PC is restarted and the listener process starts again, how does MQTT recognize that it is the same client? It seems there should be some kind of identifier in addition to the clean=false parameter.

In the Telegraf MQTT, I guess this must be the client-id, which must not be empty if the "persistent-session" is set to true. Does this sound right?

Comment: You might consider reading up on MQTT in general. There's some good introductions and tutorials that would help you understand basic use-cases like this.

Comment: It's worth noting that JMS topic subscriptions can be durable or non-durable which would be roughly equivalent to an MQTT subscriber using `false` or `true` for the `CleanSession` flag respectively. In either case, clients will only get messages sent to the topic when their subscription actually exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for persistent sessions to work, clients must reconnect with the same clientId (this is the whole point of the MQTT clientId)